# viewflipper or different activities

Tags: android, viewflipper

I was wondering which is the best way to implement the different menus in an application. For this we can use a `viewflipper` to change the displayed view, but we can also start new `activities` to generate the different menus.

Which strategy is the most used?

Answer (score 1):

`VIewFlipper` is used when you want to flip views. And if you implement VewFlipper then your code would be in one Activity class only so code won't be readable and short.

So I would suggest you to go with Activities so there way you would be able to manage code for different menus and functionalities.

Again final decision can be taken based on how your menus and functionalities for the same.